# Creating entity from view and using it in criteria query

Tags: java, jpa, entity, view

I created a view in mysql

```
create view vw_collec_sec_search as
select 
cs.collection_set_id,
cs.collection_set_name
from collection_set cs;
```

and I generated entity out of it.

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name="vw_collec_sec_search")
@NamedQuery(name="VwCollecSecSearch.findAll", query="SELECT v FROM 
VwCollecSecSearch v")
public class VwCollecSecSearch implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name="collection_set_id")
private BigInteger collectionSetId;
```

Now i am trying to use it in criteria query

```
   CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

    // Query for a List of objects.
    CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery();
    Root root = cq.from(VwCollecSecSearch.class);
```

below is the exception that i am getting

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity: class 
com.nsf.traqtion.data.view.VwCollecSecSearch
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity: class 
com.nsf.traqtion.data.view.VwCollecSecSearch
Not an entity: class com.nsf.traqtion.data.view.VwCollecSecSearch
```

I am using JPA in my project.

Comment: did you add your entity to the persistence.xml?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your entity, for that you must scan it using @EntityScan ("com.xxx.xx.model") in your main class.

Staying something more or less like this:

```
`@SpringBootApplication()
```

`@ComponentScan({`

```
"com.xxx.reporting.service",
"com.xxx.api.reporting.controller",
"com.xxx.reporting.repository"})
```

`@EntityScan("com.xxx.reporting.model")`
@EnableJpaRepositories()
public class Application { 
public static void main(String[] args) {
SpringApplication.run(Application.class , args);
}
}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the solutions.. Actually I misplaced the entity created in a different folder. so it could not scan it as an entity. Now the issue is resolved